# Is there a solution like IdentityServer4 for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, identityserver4, jwt

For ASP.NET Core there is a [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) that works with JWT to provide authentication.

I'm looking for a similar solution in Laravel. I would like to have multiple APIs in my application in order to scale out. User would be able to authenticate on one API and then use same token (JWT) on other APIs. Secondary APIs would receive encryption keys from primary API.

I'm aware that there is tymondesigns/jwt-auth and passport solutions. Could it be used in multi-API scenario? Any experience would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use laravel passport to turn your api in a multi api.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport

We use this in our own project! Works flawlessly.

Passport works just like jwt auth, you set a trait on the model that you want to be authenticated. Like the user model.

With their own generated api key to "log in" on your api.

This is a quick overview about passport, give it a try!